# npm install discord.io winston –save 404

Tags: powershell, http-status-code-404, bots, discord, command-prompt

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/) about creating a discord bot and I got to step 9 without any problem, but when I type
`npm install discord.io winston – save`
into the terminal this is what I get:

```
    npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/- - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '-@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-11T14_03_20_199Z-debug.log
```

Comment: It's written awfully on that site. The command should be `npm install discord.io winston --save`. And mind 2 minus signs, and not one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's written awfully on that site. The command should be:

`npm install discord.io winston --save`.

And mind 2 minus signs, and not one